# Retrieve sound file

Tags: vb.net, audio

I am making a dictionary using VB.NET 2008 and SQL server 2005 Traditional one the user write word and get the translation and a pronunciation sound for the word and I am facing problem with retrieve part from database. I cant retrieve the sound file from the database.

This is the code I used

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    cmd.CommandText = " select voice from lang where arabic = N'" & txtFrom.Text & "'"
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    'rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    cmd.Connection = con
    Try
        con.Open()
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While rdr.Read
            dt.Load(rdr)
            Dim stream As Byte()
            If stream Is DirectCast(dt.Rows(0)(1), Byte()) Then
                File.WriteAllBytes("D:\mad.wma", stream)

                AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "D:\mad.wma"
            End If
        End While
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        con.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the data type on the database side? You might wanna look into [blobs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48619/Reading-and-Writing-BLOB-Data-to-Microsoft-SQL-or).

Comment: You don't say what problem you are having. Do you get an exception? Is the file not created? Is the file retrieved but does not play?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go to this site: [Make a text-to-speech program](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ao89H4WVKu0&feature=player_detailpage). It will be much easier.